# How to integrate Psi (or Psi+) into the messaging menu?

Tags: messaging-menu, instant-messaging, jabber

I've just installed Psi, but it doesn't integrates into the messaging menu. Is there any way to do this? (plugin, etc...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/psi with the following content:

```
/usr/share/applications/psi.desktop
```

Logout and login again.

Comment: It works, but it's just a __launcher__. There is no indicator that Psi is running, there is no counter of new messages, and there is blue icon of new message if there is a new message.

Comment: If the application supports Indicator's then someone could make one, but if it doesn't , well... you'll never have one.

Answer (score 0):

You can try looking through the latter part of [this OMG! Ubuntu post](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/04/how-to-add-and-control-skype-via-the-ubuntu-messaging-menu/) on how to add Skype to the messaging menu. It's possible that some of the instructions there could be adapted to Psi.

Answer (score -1):

Creating of /usr/share/applications/psi.desktop is OK, but you need to create the file /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/psi (or psi-plus) and fill it with the link to psi(-plus).desktop e.g.: /usr/share/applications/psi-plus.desktop